# Why is physics.addBody throwing a table expected error?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am a complete beginner to Lua and Corona and I'm trying to teach myself how to use it. I have this code right now:

```
local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()

local cX = display.contentCenterX
local cY = display.contentCenterY

local ball = display.newCircle( cX, cY, 50 )

local rock = display.newRect( cX, 1200, 800, 100 )
rock:setFillColor( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 )

local properties = { density=1.0, friction=0.3, bounce=1 }

physics.addBody( "ball", "dynamic", properties )
physics.addBody( "rock", "static", properties )
physics.setDrawMode( "debug" )
```

However, when I run this, it gives me this error on the line that adds a physics body to ball:

`ERROR: table expected. If this is a function call, you might have used '.' instead of ':'`

I can't seem to figure out why this would be throwing an error. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Listen to error messages, they may provide help or even answer, like this time: `If this is a function call, you might have used '.' instead of ':'`

Use `physics:addBody( "ball", "dynamic", properties )` instead, like you do in `rock:setFillColor( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 )`. In fact, `a:b(c)` is eqal to `a.b(a, c)` and is used very often when you have to call a method on object like here.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I'm not really sure how I missed that one.